# AgGrid conditionally set cell type

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using the vanilla JS version of AgGrid.

Let's say I have a column called ThingType where the rows can have three values: car, bike, plane

If the value of the individual row is `car` or `bike`, I want that cell to be static. However if the text value of that cell is `plane` I'd like that individual cell to have a custom editor type where I allow editing and autocomplete.

I've seen this docs page: https://blog.ag-grid.com/conditional-formatting-for-cells-in-ag-grid/  that seems to suggest I could setup a custom cellrenderer but it's not clear with out that relates to the columntypes API or how I'd setup an individual cell to use the editbility functionality I setup in a custom column def.

Basically it feels like I want to move `type` off of `columnDef` and be cell by cell. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using conditional editing. You treat all values the same and prevent cell editing on cells that meet a specific condition (cells value with "Car" & "Bike").
[Plunker Example Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8A05sZTZqrcgnRch?open=main.js&preview)

```
{ field: 'country',
  
  // China & Russia are not editable, rest are
  editable: (params) => !(params.node.data.country === 'Russia' || 
                            params.node.data.country === 'China')
}
```